# formula field cannot trigger workflow rule

Tags: workflow, formula-field

I got a Boolean formula field which is turn to true while records created date more than 3 days. if this formula field turn to true then a workflow assume be triggered to change a lookup field (User) value. this workflow rule Evaluation Criteria I set as (created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria)

But based on my observation and result outcome, when formula field turn to true but lookup value still remain the same value.

who can give me some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow rules do not trigger based on formula field .There is an idea that you can upvote

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrIGAA0

The value of a formula field is not stored in the database hence I don't think the idea will be easier to deiver .

As an alternative you can write an apex scheduled job or look for other alternatives like time based workflow .